# Alernating content of one web site from another

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I have java/Flask (any other technology I don't know exists yet :)) question.

Suppose I have two sites: index1.html and index2.html

index1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>This example "trigger" action on another site "onclick".</p>
    <p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            //send info/request/get to localhost/index2.html for example get using XMLHttpRequest;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

index2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <script>
           window.onload= function (){ //Wait for some request from index1.html than do something for example change string in demo}
       </script>
    <body>

    <p id="demo">To change</p>

</body>
</html>
```

It can be done partially with Flask but every time i trigger from index1.html index2.html I have to refresh manually index2.html.

Maybe there is another technology which help me to do that

Comment: Sites or pages on same origin? You cannot pass data from one origin to another using client side technology like localStorage - you could pass in the URL

Comment: yep how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` `storage` event or `SharedWorker` to communicate between browsing contexts.

index1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="page2.html" target="_blank">page2</a>
    <p>This example "trigger" action on another site "onclick".</p>
    <p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</p>
    <script>
        localStorage.clear(); // clear `localStorage`
        function myFunction() {
           localStorage.setItem("page1", "value");
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

index2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
  window.onload = function() { 
    if (localStorage.getItem("page1") != null) {
      document.getElementById("demo").textContent = localStorage.getItem("page1");
    } 
    // do stuff at `storage` event
    onstorage = e => {
      if (e.key === "page1") {
        document.getElementById("demo").textContent = e.newValue;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<body>
  <p id="demo">To change</p>
</body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/4Xz58S5MDidORm4CAPco?p=preview

Comment: on the same origin yes

Comment: @mplungjan `storage` event is dispatched when `oldValue` is changed.

Comment: You are not passing anything if you clear localStorage before reading it

Comment: @mplungjan Not sure what you mean. Clearing `localStorage` should ensure that whenever the link at page1.html is clicked the `storage` event should be dispatched at page2.html if the page is reloaded. We could go further and clear `localStorage` at each `storage` event at page2.html

Comment: @mplungjan For example, if you comment `localStorage.clear()` at page1.html `storage` event will only be dispatched at most once at page2.html if the value set at `localStorage` does not change at page1.html

Comment: @mplungjan If you are referencing the call to `.clear()` at page2.html, see updated post.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. Is there any way to do it on remote server? Json exchange etc. ? I  found that i can only make get request and wait for response, not just waiting for some request and then act.

Comment: @ŁukaszAndrzejewski How is a server related to the original question?

Comment: Im just looking for some way to force site (index2.html) to wait for request from index1.html than take action, could be server.

Comment: ok, I done it using websockets, maybe there is better way but works :)